# Rcpp sort descending

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I cannot sort in descending order using `Rcpp`

Sort in ascending order:

```
NumericVector sortIt(NumericVector v){
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    return v;
}
```

Attempt to sort in descending order:

```
NumericVector sortIt(NumericVector v){
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), std::greater<int>()); // does not work returns ascending
    return v;
}
```

and

```
NumericVector sortIt(NumericVector v){
    std::sort(numbers.rbegin(), numbers.rend()); // errors
    return v;
}
```

Comment: FWIW, an `Rcpp::NumericVector` is a vector of `double`s, not `int`s, so you probably want to use `std::greater<double>`.

Comment: Indeed, this works. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This functionality has since been [added](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/pull/527) (Rcpp version >= 0.12.7) to the `Vector` member function `sort`. This is necessary for sorting `CharacterVector` objects in particular (either ascending or descending) because the underlying element type requires special handling, and is incompatible with `std::sort` + `std::greater` (as well as certain other STL algorithms).

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::CharacterVector char_sort(Rcpp::CharacterVector x) {
    Rcpp::CharacterVector res = Rcpp::clone(x);
    res.sort(true);
    return res;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector dbl_sort(Rcpp::NumericVector x) {
    Rcpp::NumericVector res = Rcpp::clone(x);
    res.sort(true);
    return res;
}
```

Note the use of `clone` to avoid modifying the input vector.

---

```
char_sort(c("a", "c", "b", "d"))
# [1] "d" "c" "b" "a"

dbl_sort(rnorm(5))
# [1]  0.8822381  0.7735230  0.3879146 -0.1125308 -0.1929413
```

Answer (score 0):

This works on my rig. I don't quite understand why. Maybe someone more qualified than I can explain precisely why this works but the other formulations fail?

```
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction('NumericVector sortIt(NumericVector v){
    int len = v.size();
    std::sort(&v[0], &v[len], std::greater<int>());
    return v;
            }')

 sortIt(sample(1:20))
 [1] 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
```